# How to check if a value is NOT a list

Tags: python, list

I need to check if a value is a list before carrying out the rest of the code. The for loop should only be run if my_list is a list.

```
    sum=0
    if not list:
        print("The input is not a list or is empty.")
        exit()

    for item in (list):
        sum+=1
    print("The length of the list is ",sum)

my_list = "Hello";
list_length(my_list)
```

The code works as expected when my_list is an actual list, but if I set it equal to a string, "Hello" at the moment in my code, the output is 5, I want it to not have an output.

Comment: I believe you forgot your function definition line at the top.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```py
if isinstance([], list):
    print("this is list")
```

to check.
and if you want to check is subclass, you can use

```py
if issubclass(sub_class, your_class):
    print(f"this is subclass of {your_class}")
```